# Webscraping with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, nlp

i'm trying to scrape some data for training but I'm stuck.

I would like to scrape the date, not just the year, but I couldn't quite figure out how to do this for now.

Here's the segment I would like to scrape :

[htmlscrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9T2P.png)

And here's my script so far :

```
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

url = "https://www.senscritique.com/films/tops/top111"

results = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")



titles = []
years = []
notes = []
synopsys = []
infos = []
dates = []

movie_div = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'elto-flexible-column')

for container in movie_div:
    title = container.h2.a.text
    titles.append(title)


    year = container.h2.find('span', class_ = 'elco-date').text
    year = year.replace('(', '')
    year = year.replace(')', '')
    years.append(year)


    sy = container.find('p', class_ = 'elco-description').text
    synopsys.append(sy)


    note = float(container.div.a.text)
    notes.append(note)



    info = container.find('p', class_ = 'elco-baseline elco-options').text
    #type = re.sub(r'[a-z]+', '', type)
    
    infos.append(info)

    soup = container.find('p', class_ = 'elco-baseline elco-options')

    for i in soup:
        i = soup.find('time')

        dates.append(i)

print(dates[0])
```

And here's the results :

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krJlE.png)

I would like to just have the "1957-04-10" or the "10 avril 1957", whatever ! But I cannot figure it out ! I tried many things but it's the best I had so far.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.text` property of `<time>` tag to get the time:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.senscritique.com/films/tops/top111'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for movie in soup.select('.elto-item'):
    title = movie.select_one('[id^="product-title"]').text
    time = movie.select_one('time')
    time = time.text if time else '-'
    print('{:<40} {}'.format(title, time))
```

Prints:

```
12 hommes en colère                      10 avril 1957
Harakiri                                 16 septembre 1962
Barberousse                              3 avril 1965
Le Bon, la Brute et le Truand            23 décembre 1966
Les Sept Samouraïs                       26 avril 1954
Il était une fois dans l'Ouest           21 décembre 1968
Il était une fois en Amérique            23 mai 1984
Le Parrain                               24 mars 1972
Le Trou                                  18 mars 1960
Dersou Ouzala                            2 août 1975
Point limite                             7 octobre 1964
Entre le ciel et l'enfer                 1 mars 1963

...and so on.
```

Comment: Ooow, I used text but it didn't work. I guess I was doing something wrong. Thanks for the answer I will try it out like you :)

Comment: Thanks it work ! I didn't know select_one. That's nice. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this would do it for you, just returning the date.

```
tags = soup('time')
date_formatted = list()
for tag in tags:
    date_formatted.append((tag.contents[0])))
    print(date_formatted[0])
```